# Pegar dados GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Preciso de uma função em javascript que traga os dados preenchidos na `gridview` e coloque em uma `lista` , pesquisando encontrei a seguinte função:

```
        function pegarDadosGrid(e) {
            var dados = e.component.getDataSource().items();
            $("input[name='myHiddenInput']").val(JSON.stringify(items));
        }
```

Mas não consigo saber se está funcionando, não tem como colocar `break point`

Como posso pegar os dados de um grid e colocar em uma `variável` utilizando javascript

Meu grid:

```
            <div class="divGrid">
            @(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<ContatosViewModel>().ID("gridContainer")
                                            .ColumnAutoWidth(true)
                                            .Height(200)
                                            .Width(758)
                                            .ShowBorders(true)
                                            .Paging(paging => paging.Enabled(false))
                                            .Editing(editing =>
                                            {
                                                editing.Mode(DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.GridEditMode.Row);
                                                editing.AllowAdding(true);
                                                editing.AllowDeleting(true);
                                                editing.AllowUpdating(true);
                                            })
                                            .Columns(columns =>
                                            {
                                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Con_nome);
                                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Con_vinculo);
                                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Con_fone);
                                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Con_fax);
                                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Con_celular);
                                                columns.AddFor(m => m.Con_email);
                                            }).DataSource(AgenciaController.ListaContatos)
                                            .OnContentReady("pegarDadosGrid")
            )
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na function que você citou você pode colocar *debugger;* para debugar o código js.

```
 function pegarDadosGrid(e) {
            var dados = e.component.getDataSource().items();
            debugger; // quando vc chamar pegarDadosGrid, a execução deve parar aqui
            $("input[name='myHiddenInput']").val(JSON.stringify(dados)); // aqui deve ser dados em vez de items
        }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, esta funcionando, vllww